# numeric++ in VB.NET as in C++ or C#

Tags: vb.net, ide

I would like to know if there is any way to add 1 to a numeric value as in C++ or C# by using for example

```
i++
```

I tried it, but it VB.NET's IDE did not like it.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the shortest way to increment a value is  `i += 1`

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why this is so. If I were a VB.NET dev at MS, I would really like to include this feature. It would be so simply to implement. Also, I would allow users to type ";" at the end of a line although it is not a VB standard. That would make programming much more comfortable for users who switch between different programming languages very often.